# Anchor linking when we have a persistent bar at the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, scroll

Interesting "problem".  We spent a lot of time making our top bar persistent on the site.  Now, whenever an anchor is clicked on a page, the browser takes me to a section, but because there's a persistent bar, that section start is hidden behind the persistent bar :)

Is there any clever idea where I can track this via Jquery or something, and instead of the browser default, perhaps make such scrolling to anchor work with "animation" and "scrolltop"? -- And then take the user to about 30px *above* the offset of the anchor, so that even with the persistent bar there, the intended destination visible now below the persistent bar?

I can control this when a link is clicked within the page, but how do I control when users come into a page via an anchor. Thanks!

Comment: do you mean a 'fixed' bar?

Comment: Yes the persistent bar uses the css position:fixed but dynamically, when users scroll down past a certain location.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this jquery example. [Smooth-Scrolling](http://www.devirtuoso.com/2011/11/smooth-scrolling-in-jquery/) It also shows how to set an offset variable so you can set the buffer zone of your top bar

Comment: Hi. Is it possible to use this smooth scrolling in such a way that inside the HTML nothing changes at all? We just create sections and link to them, and some totally separate Jquery included in the footer (which content guys never touch or even know about) takes care of the smooth scrolling?

Comment: Do you mean like having a separate .js file that wouldn't be embedded in the HTML? If so <script src="/Scripts/smoothScrolling.js">

Answer (score 1):

You can isolate the anchor hash with window.location.hash. Depending on the rest of your URL you may have to massage your hashTag value a bit. Then once you have a jQuery object you can do as you will.

HTML:

```
< a id="sectionName" name="sectionName"></ a>
```

JS:

```
var hashTag = window.location.hash;
$(hashTag).css({ position: "absolute", top: "30px" });
```